# How can design multithreading and read same input

Tags: python, multithreading

i will like to design my platform to calculate something and the structure is ,

one big file (maybe 5gb or 10gb)
20 threading and execute different algorithm

the current structure of mine is 20 thread open the big file by itself
and then read line by line to execute by each thread
however, i would like to design a new structure that open big file just one time , 
and every thread read the same memory block ,

i survey mmap and multiprocess.array ,but still have not idea how to apply it safety and easily.

can anybody help me ? thanks.

Comment: please show us some of your attempts.

Comment: I would use mmap and map file only for reading, that way it would be safe to share between threads.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying file handle generated when opening a file can be used for reading at one point of the file only. You cannot read multiple offset with the same file handle.

So you should use one thread reading the file while other threads read a kind of queue generated by the first thread with the file buffers.

Comment: do you mean i read file to memory and then pass the memory to each threading ?

Comment: yes but not the whole file in memory, buffer after buffer to a void memory over-consumption.